# Is there a way to add all commands from files that ends with ".py" from a folder inside a folder?

Tags: python, discord, nextcord

So ive been watching some cogs tutorial and thought that i should combine some of the ideas together and came up with this idea that will make my folder more neat and easy to read.

As an example:

> Modules(folder)/Moderation(folder)/Lock.py

> Modules(folder)/Game(folder)/Clown.py

and many more files that endswith ".py" in unique folders inside the folder "Modules"

I tried doing this but failed miserably in the end:

```py
for folder in os.listdir("Modules"):
    for file in folder:
        if file.endswith(".py"):
            if os.path.exists(os.path.join("Modules", folder, file)):
                client.load_extension(f'Modules.{folder}.{file}')
```

Is this actually possible and if yes please help me.

Comment: `os.listdir("Modules")` will only get **one level** folders such as `Moderation`, you need check `if os.path.isdir(file )` then `os.listdir` again.

Comment: im not sure if i understand where to put `if os.path.isdir(file)` because i got an error of the variable file is referenced before assignment

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do exactly; could you be more specific as to what exactly doesn't work? I don't understand what you want to do with the "Modules" folder.

```py
from pathlib import Path

ROOTDIR: Path = Path("/absolute/path/to/Modules").resolve()

for pyfile in ROOTDIR.rglob("*.py"):

    # Use only the part of the path relative to Modules directory
    # and convert it to a dot-delimited string.
    ext: str = '.'.join(pyfile.parts[pyfile.parts.index("Modules"):])

    client.load_extension(ext)
```

Are you looking for something like this? You can traverse the entire directory tree with glob patterns using `Path.rglob`.

`pathlib` is in the standard library and makes working with filepaths and directories easier and more readable.

Comment: thx for the suggestion but the bot still can't find my commands

Comment: oops i just realise u asked me some questions. The modules file stores those unique file (the Moderation and Game folder). I keep getting errors like `nextcord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "help" is not found`

Comment: I don't know what nextcord is. Have you tried consulting the documentation for that package? What is ```client.load_extension``` supposed to do? What do the docs tell you? Regarding 
```nextcord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "help" is not found```; Can you look at the traceback and perhaps use a debugger to see where it goes awry?

Comment: nextcord is a discord bot library and idk either since im really slow at learning and im quite new in coding

Comment: You'll be fine. I do think you are far more likely to get help if you explain where exactly you are stuck though, and show you've put some effort in finding the answer to your question yourself first. Assume the people responding don't know about your specific problem nor its context. 9/10 times, I've found the answer to my own question by the time I'd written a post here.

Do you know where you can find the documentation? Do you know how to use a debugger? No shame _at_ _all_ in not knowing; everyone started like that. But willingness to learn goes a long way.

Comment: i see thank you for the advice ill try and explain my problem better next time

Answer (score 0):

The way you have done it is absolutely fine except that `load_extension()` takes the name of the file containing the cog class without the `.py` extension which you have forgotten to remove.

```py
for folder in os.listdir("./Modules"): # ./ is to start at the current working directory
    for file in folder:
        if file.endswith(".py"):
             client.load_extension(f'Modules.{folder}.{file[:-3]}')
```